# convert a string into something reversible, in Java

Tags: java, java-8, hbase, bijection

I have a lot of urls that serve as keys in a HBase table. Since they "all" start by `http://`, Hbase puts them in the same node. Thus I end with a node at +100% and the other idle.

So, I need to map the url to something hash-like, but reversible. Is there any simple, standard, and fast way to do that in JAVA8.

**I look for random (linear) distribution of prefixes.**

Note:

- reversing the url is not interesting since a lot of urls end with `/ ? =` and risk to unbalance the distribution.
- I do not need encryption, but I can accept it.
- I do not look for compression, but it is welcome if possible :)

Thanks,
Costin

Comment: remove the http:// ?

Comment: Why dont you just remove the protocol from the url before saving, maybe add another column for that, if you really need it?
You can't reverse a hash. It's simply not how they work.

Comment: I have to keep the urls complete. I know a hash does not the job, I think of something like AES or ZIP? Thanks :)

Comment: I'll only add that you don't want to think casually about your hbase row key. It's probably the single most critical design decision. You don't want to have 100's million rows prior to discovering distribution is bad or you can't read the data the way you want efficiently. This is a decent read: http://blog.sematext.com/2012/04/09/hbasewd-avoid-regionserver-hotspotting-despite-writing-records-with-sequential-keys/

Comment: @ax123man I've read the blog post you mention few hours ago, but this solution involves too many changes in the application. Nice, but we cannot do it today. Thanks

Comment: you should add how you want to query the data to your question.  without that we are missing a big part.

Comment: I don’t know HBase, but I can’t believe that it has such an issue. Is there really no way to switch to a different key to node distribution algorithm?

Comment: @Holger I there is a HBase solution I'd like to use it. But I did not find any. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinSerrano I only do get and put. Thus, the accepted solution is fine. I do some scan on other tables, but this is another subject. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a single, standard way.

One thing you can do is to prefix the key with its hash. Something like:

```
a01cc0fe http://...
```

That's easily reversible (just snip off the hash chars, which you can make be a fixed length) and will get you good distribution.

The hash code for a string is stable and consistent across JVMs. The algorithm for computing it is specified in [`String.hashCode`'s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()), so you can consider it part of the contract of how a String works.

Comment: Is the hash of a string the same on all JVMs, on all machines? If so, it might do the job.

Comment: I have finally used this idea. I've prefixed the url by the first 2 bytes in hexa from its md5. The hashCode() is not good for balancing purposes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add prefix of the hash code encoded by 36 decimal number [0-9a-z].

```
public static String encode(String s) {
    return Integer.toString(s.hashCode() & 0xffffff, 36) + "#" + s;
}

public static String decode(String s) {
    return s.replaceFirst("^[^#]*#", "");
}
```

sample:

```
http://google.com/  <-> 5o07l#http://google.com/
```

Comment: Hi, I've used this idea, but with better hashing (the first bytes of md5) Thanks.